# Clipboard Manager for Windows that allows one paste of all items in one fell swoop

Tags: windows-7, clipboard, utility

I need a feature I haven't been able to figure out in my existing clipboard manager, Arsclip: I'd like to be able to paste all the existing entries in the clipboard list with just one or two clicks or a keyboard shortcut.

I would prefer a free tool but for the right tool I could make a reasonable payment.

Should be able to copy text from any area on the computer, into a web form's input box, or into a text file, or Word 2010.

Update: I just found https://superuser.com/a/1011616/433830.  I would like to be able to set ONE hot key to paste everything at once, without needing to perform multiple steps.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is such a basic, yet vital, utility, I have spent years looking for the ideal clipboard manager, and for me it is [Ditto](https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io/). It is [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) including for commercial porpoises.

I would recommend first clearing the clipboard – launch Ditto, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then hit the delete key, or right-click and select delete.

Now, make all your selections to populate the clipboard, and finally, launch Ditto, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, navigate to where you want to paste and hit Ctrl-v. I have just tested this and it works.

Easy peasy, plus Ditto is the best clipboard manager that there is.

---

Features

- Easy to use interface
- Search and paste previous copy entries
- Keep multiple computer's clipboards in sync
- Data is encrypted when sent over the network
- Accessed from tray icon or global hot key
- Select entry by double click, enter key or drag drop
- Paste into any window that excepts standard copy/paste entries
- Display thumbnail of copied images in list
- Full Unicode support (display foreign characters)
- UTF-8 support for language files (create language files in any language)
- Uses sqlite database (www.sqlite.org)

and many more features. My favo(u)rite is sticky clips. Ditto also happens to be open-source and can be used as a portable application too.

[image: Ditto screenshot]

In fairness to the other suggestion, you might want to read [Clipboard Master vs Ditto: Comparing 2 Cool Windows Clipboard Managers](https://www.guidingtech.com/45512/clipboard-master-vs-ditto/) and make your own choice.

Although, [this page](https://techwiser.com/best-clipboard-manager-for-windows/) says

> As good as it is, the user interface of Clipboard Master is not the best and as a result, there is a good amount of learning curve to get used to Clipboard Master.

and

> Wrapping Up: Best Clipboard Manager for Windows
>
> We saw some of the best clipboard manager tools for Windows. If you are looking for freeware that just works, Ditto is a good option. If you need a clipboard manager that sync between your Mac and Windows PC, 1Clipboard should work. Or for more sync options i.e. Android and iOS, try Clipboard fusion. Though that comes with a price tag of $15 per user.
>
> Finally, if you are someone who likes to install one app that does everything, that Clipboard master is a better choice. The free version comes with screenshot capture and text expander option along with clipboard manager. But on the flip side, it doesn’t have the best UI out there.

I suggest waiting until all answers are in, then reading reviews of them all and taking them for a test drive. You might also want to consider whether you will swap over to a new clipboard manager, or stick with your existing one the majority of the time, and only use one of the answers here for special circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [Clipboard Master](https://www.clipboardmaster.com/) fits your requirement

> ### Multi-Clipboard
>
> In contrast to Windows, Clipboard Master features a multi-clipboard that allows you to access previously copied entries. Clipboard Master stores up to 10,000 entries.
>
> Text, images, files and folders that you copy in Windows or a Windows program are automatically added to the Clipboard Master multi-clipboard. The newest entry is always added to the top of the list in the multi-clipboard.
>
> Example: You have to paste multiple cells form Excel into a Word document. Use Clipboard Master to simply copy the cells from Excel one after the other and then switch to Word. You can then paste the copied text all at once. In doing so, you can select whether the text should be pasted separately by blank space, tab, new line or another character.
>
> Or you run across a recipe collection in the Internet and would like to send links to certain recipes to an acquaintance via email. Use Clipboard Master to copy the links of the recipes one after another and then paste them in the desired order in your email program. In contrast to the Windows clipboard, you do not have to constantly switch between the browser and your email program; instead you can first *"collect" all of the links* and then **paste them into your email in a single second step**.
>
> Overview of the "Multi-Clipboard" Feature:
>
> - Automatic copying to the multi-clipboard: All entries copied to the Windows clipboard are also copied by Clipboard Master.
> - Paste from the multi-clipboard via key combination, double clicking on an entry in Clipboard Master or using the mouse via the Clipboard Master tray icon.
> - Paste the last x or multiple entries separated by tab, blank spaces, new lines or any other character
> - Directly paste the last 1 to 10 entries.
> - The entries also remain available after turning off the computer.
> - You can define the settings a time after which the entries should be automatically deleted.
> - All key combinations can be changed in the Clipboard Master settings.
> - This also works in Windows 8/8.1 apps.
>
> https://www.clipboardmaster.com/features/features-tour/multi-clipboard.html
>
> ### Clipboard with Multiple Entries
>
> ...
>
> Paste content into any Windows program
>
> - With Clipboard Master, you can paste text and images (also multiple) into any Windows program.
> - Using the Clipboard Master multi-clipboard, not only can you paste the last copy, you can also use the previous copies. You can paste a single entry from your copies, paste entries in any order or also paste multiple entries at once.
> - As Clipboard Master supports nearly all Windows program, you can automatically fill out forms with the multi-clipboard or distribute collected text throughout Excel table cells.
> - Clipboard Master comes with many frequently needed text templates for letters and email.
>
> https://www.clipboardmaster.com/features/features-tour/clipboard-with-multiple-entries.html

---

You can also paste all items in Ditto clip with the following steps

- Open the clip list by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>
- Select all clips by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to paste

Answer (score 0):

With [Text Blaze](https://blaze.today/) you can assign shortcuts (like /sig, /style, etc. in this picture) to your snippets:

[image]

There are also versions for Windows, macOS, and a Chrome extension.

Additionally, with the extension, right-clicking on a text input box will display a Text Blaze option in the menu. Your snippets will appear in that menu and can be inserted from there.

[image]

There are many functions such as formulas, teams, rules, forms, reading websites, sharing snippets, tables, etc. which you can consult in the [documentation](https://blaze.today/docs/).